# Eclipse RCP connecting to oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create simple database application using Eclipse RCP with Oracle in the back end.  I have kept ojdbc14.jar in the classpath of eclipse and its showing me the class when I press

```
Cntr-Shift-T
```

It show the class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` present in the classpath

[image]

But when I run my program its showing error message as

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at veridinview.model.ModelProvider.<init>(ModelProvider.java:37)
    at veridinview.model.ModelProvider.getInstance(ModelProvider.java:88)
    at veridinview.View.createPartControl(View.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2632)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$27.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:2967)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.busyOpenPage(WorkbenchWindow.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$23.runWithException(Workbench.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at veridinview.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

Where can I put my Jar file so that eclipse RCP can see it?

Oracle version- 10g express
OS: windows 7

Comment: Which project have you build `JavaProject` ,  `DynamicWebProject` or `StaticWebProject`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Where can I put my Jar file so that eclipse RCP can see it?
```

In an RCP project you can not include JAR Files directly. One way to include is create separate plug-in project from JAR file and include that new created plug-in as Dependency.

Please Refer [Cannot connect MySQL in Eclipse RCP IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868546/cannot-connect-mysql-in-eclipse-rcp-ide)